# ASP.NET Membership - Add extra field to ASP.Net Login page

Tags: asp.net-membership

Currently in My application, validating the users using the ASP.Net membership provider and the ASP.Net default Login page contains only Username and Password. This is working fine with this two fields. But as per my current requirement, need an extra field "Company" display as dropdownlist in ASP.Net Login page and validate the three Company, Username and Password using the ASP.NET membership provider. Is this possible or not, customize the ASP.Net Login page with an extra field using ASP.Net membership provider? Could you please give me some ideas how could I approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Membership provider's ValidateUser method only accept two parameters - username and password. Even if you override it, you cannot pass three parameters.

```
ValidateUser(string username, string password)
```

Basically, you cannot use Login control to validate for user. Instead, you want to validate user by yourself. Here is an sample code -

[image]

Note: I strip out codes in Login control for demo purpose.

```
<asp:Login ID="LoginUser" runat="server" OnAuthenticate="LoginUser_Authenticate">
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="UserName" runat="server" />
        <asp:TextBox ID="Password" runat="server" TextMode="Password" />
        <asp:DropDownList ID="CompanyDropDownList" runat="server">
            <asp:ListItem Text="One" Value="1" />
            <asp:ListItem Text="Two" Value="2" />
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:Button ID="LoginButton" runat="server" CommandName="Login" 
        Text="Log In" ValidationGroup="LoginUserValidationGroup" />
    </LayoutTemplate>
</asp:Login>

protected void LoginUser_Authenticate(object sender, AuthenticateEventArgs e)
{
    var companyName = LoginUser.FindControl("CompanyDropDownList") 
        as DropDownList;

    if(MyValidateUser(LoginUser.UserName, LoginUser.Password, 
        companyName.SelectedValue))
    {
        FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(LoginUser.UserName, false);

        // Do something
    }
}
```

**Please make sure you use new [ASP.NET Universal Providers](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingSystemWebProvidersASPNETUniversalProvidersForSessionMembershipRolesAndUserProfileOnSQLCompactAndSQLAzure.aspx)**

Comment: Thanks...I have tried in this way but facing some problem with the CompanyDropDownList, retrieving the selected dropdown item by using Login.FIndControl method. And also my requirement is beyond this functionality, switch to company databases and validate the users. So I thought to implement the Forms authentication with custom login page and switch to company databases and finally validate user and allow access to authorized page. Any how Thank you for your suggestions which helped in learning new things.

Comment: Hmm This sort of works, thanks.  <LayoutTemplate> is a revelation :)  But looses the field labels, title bar and "Forgotten password" link :(  It is also not clear to me if the user & password fields remain correctly mapped, compared to defaults. Hmm

Comment: Aah simpler to use VS Designer to convert the default UI to a template first :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use the Profile Provider for this.

Alternatively, you could create your own table(s) that store additional user-related information. This is a little more work since you're on the hook for creating your own tables and creating the code to get and save data to and from these tables, but I find that using custom tables in this way allows for greater flexibility and more maintainability than the Profile Provider (specifically, the default Profile Provider, SqlProfileProvider, which stores profile data in an inefficient, denormalized manner).

Take a look at this tutorial, where you can find a walk through this process: Storing Additional User Information.

Comment: Thanks...Tutorial link is not provided. Could you please provide the same.

Comment: dont forget to accept my answer:    http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/security/membership/storing-additional-user-information-cs