# Getting userId of logged in user returns null

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-membership

I am designing an ASP.net MVC4 application and I need to get the current user ID so that I'll save it in a table in my database as an owner id for a group.

This is the code I am using:

```
public ActionResult CreateGroup(string groupName, string description)
{
       if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
       {
           Group group = new Group();
           Random random = new Random();
           int groupId = random.Next(1, 2147483647);

           using (CodeShareEntities conn = new CodeShareEntities())
           {
               try
               {
                        int ownerId = (int) Membership.GetUser(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name).ProviderUserKey;

                        group.GroupId = groupId;
                        group.GroupName = groupName;
                        group.Description = description;
                        group.OwnerId = ownerId;

                        conn.Group.Add(group);
                        conn.SaveChanges();
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        ModelState.AddModelError("", e.Message);
                    }
                }

                return View("ThisGroup");
          }
          else 
          {
          return View("../Shared/NotLoggedIn");
  }
```

I am getting a NullReferenceException on this line:

```
int ownerId = (int) Membership.GetUser(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name).ProviderUserKey;
```

although the username is returning correctly. What can be the problem? I am still new to web applications and I really can't figure this out!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are using a custom membership provider, I believe that the ProvidersUserKey is a Guid.

```
(Guid) Membership.GetUser(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name).ProviderUserKey;
```

Comment: What is a Guid ? and how can I convert that to an integer so I can save it in my database please? Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.it is work if you use aspnet membership provider.

```
MembershipUser user = Membership.GetUser(HttpContext.User.Identity.Name);
    Guid guid = (Guid)user.ProviderUserKey;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the helper method to retrieves current Logged-in user's ID.

**Please note that ASP.Net Membership use Guid as ID (rather than integer).**

```
public static Guid? UserId
{
    get
    {
        try
        {
            Guid? userId = null;
            if (HttpContext.Current != null &&  
               HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                MembershipUser currentUser = Membership.GetUser();
                userId = (Guid)currentUser.ProviderUserKey;
            }
            return userId;
        }
        catch
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

**Note:** you want to check the returned `UserId` is not `null` and `group.OwnerId` is `Guid` too; otherwise, your save statement will fail.

Comment: thanks for your answer :) .. So there isn't a way in which I convert a guid to integer ? My database field OwnerId is int type and sql server has no guid type

Comment: OwnerId must be Guid if you want OwnerId as a foreign key of Users table's UserId. Otherwise, you cannot make a relation between them. Here is the sample http://stackoverflow.com/a/15745316/296861